# Why is Spring Boot Starter Mongodb Reactive not saving the List fields of my entities?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, reactive-programming

I can't figure out why the List fields of my entities are not being persisted when saved using Spring Boot Mongodb Reactive.

This is how my Contact entity looks like:

```
@Data
@Document
public class Contact {
    private String id;

    @DBRef
    private User owner;

    private List<String> messageIds;

    private Message lastMessage;

    private LocalDateTime lastMessageAt;

    public boolean addMessageId(String message) {
        if (messageIds == null) {
            messageIds = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return messageIds.add(message);
    }
}
```

I save it using this repository:

```
public interface ContactRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Contact, String> {

    Mono<Contact> findByOwnerId(String ownerId);

}
```

Everything but the messageIds list is getting persisted just fine. I already switched from directly having a list of Messages, but this didn't help so far.

The debugger also shows the messageIds list right there before the repo save call.

Already searched for a solution without any luck. Am I missing the obvious here?

Answer (score 0):

It really was that simple:

I forgot to subscribe to the inner observables that saved my entities in my reactive chain.

Comment: can you elaborate more about subscribing inner observables?